# How to rename a file test.c to Test.c in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I have a file of name: test.c in perforce, but i want it as Test.c (capital T). 
**I tried rename, delete and then add but both methods are not useful!** The file gets update in my machine, but when some one else accesses it, the file remains, test.c itself, not Test.c!
What can i do in this case?
And i have many files of same name inside the directory in perforce, i want to rename them all.
Ex:
dir1->test.c , dir2
dir2 ->test.c , dir3
dir3->test.c

This should become:
dir1->Test.c , dir2
dir2 ->Test.c , dir3
dir3->Test.c

Comment: What kind of machine is your server hosted on, Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file name appears correct when looking at the tree in P4V, but is the wrong case on the client machine, try removing the file from the workspace and then resyncing. Windows won't rename the file if it's already on disk because it's a case insensitive file system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longstanding bug with Perforce/Helix that they have consistently refused to fix for over 14 years.

The Helix knowledgebase workaround does NOT work, don't waste your time.

The closest I've found to a solution is the following:

1. Rename the file to an interim string that you will never use in the future and have never used before - eg add a UUID postfix
2. Commit this change
3. Copy up to the highest applicable parent stream
4. Merge down into ALL streams that will ever need the change and have the original erroneous name. You can filter the merge down to just the rename/move operation.
5. Get Latest on ALL Windows workspaces for the affected streams
6. Rename the file to the final case-sensitive string
7. Commit this change
8. Copy up as per step 3
9. Merge down as per step 4

Important: You MUST copy up and merge down while the file has the temporary name.

Perforce *does not* take interim changes into account when merging down or copying up - this is different to every other source control system that I'm aware of and caused much heartache.

Note: While file history across the rename is apparently preserved in the database, it appears that you can only see that the rename occurred and cannot diff or merge across the change.